# Heroku Discord Bot Offline When Deployed?

Tags: python, heroku, discord.py, bots

I'm currently creating a Discord bot using Python-- Specifically through the PyCharms IDE via JetBrains.  My issue with using PyCharm as the IDE is there is no integration for Heroku and using console commands w/ Github is the nightmare of all nightmares.

I posted my code on github, the app deployed successfully through Heroku but the app is offline.  I've checked everywhere and none of the solutions work for me.

Here are my files and their contents currently:

main.py

```
import discord
from urllib.request import urlopen
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')

token = "***********************"
client = discord.Client()
URL = "https://www.surrenderat20.net/search/label/PBE/"
page = urlopen(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
pbe_titles = soup.find_all('h1', attrs={'class': 'news-title'})
links = []

for tag in pbe_titles:
    for anchor in tag.find_all('a'):
        links.append(tag.text.strip())
        links.append(anchor['href'])
output = '\n'.join(str(line) for line in links[:2])
print(output)


@bot.command(name='pbe')
async def peebeeee(ctx):
    response = output
    await ctx.send(response)

bot.run(token)
```

I'm *ing off my Token code.  I'd make an .env if I had any interest in sharing the code but .env doesnt seem to work well in Pycharm.

Procfile:
`worker: python bot/main.py`
Requirements.txt:
`discord.py`
Runtime.txt:
 `python-3.8.7`

My current github is structured such that all files listed are on the main page including the folder: bot which holds the main.py  ** I have the Git listed as private atm

If someone could please shine some light as to why my discord bot won't stay online even if Heroku deploys it successfully, that would be great. Thank you.

Comment: Change `worker` to simply `worker: python main.py`. Also, if you find the Heroku commands to be a nightmare on your IDE, what you can do is you can connect your GitHub repo to your application on Heroku, so that everytime you push code to your remote repo, it will automatically deploy to your Heroku application.

Comment: will this work even when my main.py is inside a folder titled "bot" in the repo?

Comment: Oh I thought you said that you had all the files listed out on the main page

Comment: The only other things I can think about is either getting rid of your `Runtime.txt` file, since I don't have that and my bot works perfectly fine on Heroku. Another thing might be to make sure that you have all the necessary buildpacks required, particularly the `heroku/python` buildpack. Lastly, you might need to add more items in your `Requirements.txt`. I, for example, have `git+https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py`, 
`PyNaCl==1.3.0`, 
`dnspython==1.16.0`, 
`pandas`, and
`async-timeout==3.0.1`.

Comment: Hmm. I'll add those and give it a try.  Is the ```requirements.txt``` file name case sensitive? I'm just really confused, unfortunately.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it is case sensitive. If you're confused, you can watch [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BPvg9bndP1U) which provides a complete walkthrough on how to set up a bot on Heroku; it's the video I used to get started. Keep in mind one thing, however, that in the video, he puts `git+https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py@rewrite` in his requirement file, which is incorrect as someone pointed out in the comment section. Rather, you would put in `git+https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py`.

Comment: It was actually all of my requirements that was messed up causing the bot to fail.  I was missing a few requirements.  Appreciate it!!!

Comment: No problem, good luck!

Answer (score 0):

This **[repo](https://github.com/audieni/discord-py-heroku)** might be helpful as it gives some insight into creating a bot and hosting it on Heroku.

The only thing that I can think of that you maybe didn't do is that you didn't turn the worker on:

> Under 'Resources', do the following:
> Click on the 'Pencil' icon.
> Switch the worker from off to on.
> Click 'Confirm' to finalize the decision.